# Deploying Web API and Angular

Tags: angular, azure, .net-core

I have two azure deployed urls for web api and angular. Can i have one single URL that deploys both URLs in one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you deploying your angular app and webapi, is angular app going to a storage account and webapi going to app service?

Comment: It looks like you deployed the API and angular to two app services. And you want to find a solution to deploy the API and angular to one app service.